# Variable not saving on .txt (medium)

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering why my variable from my php page isn't saving to my .txt. I have posted the code below. All the variables match.

Everytime the new page refreshes, the message disappears and I've checked my txt file, the variables are not saved in an array as it should be.

```js
function updateData() {
     $.getJSON("#host/information.txt", 
      function(data) {
       var senator = data[0];
       var cmicrophone = data[1];
       var microphone = data[2];
       var words = data[3];
       $("#java").text(senator + cmicrophone +  microphone + words);}
       );
    }
```

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 
 if(isset($_POST["senator"]) && isset($_POST["cmicrophone"]) && isset($_POST["microphone"]) && isset($_POST["words"])) { // If the page receives POST data, it needs to be stored
    $senator = $_POST["senator"];
 $cmicrophone = $_POST["cmicrophone"];
    $microphone = $_POST["microphone"];
 $words = $_POST["words"];
    $data = json_encode(Array($senator, $cmicrophone, $microphone, $words)); // Put values into an array and encode it for storage
    file_put_contents('information.txt', $data); // Put the JSON-encoded array into a text file. This function replaces the contents of the text file, which is exactly what is needed in this application. To append instead of replacing the contents, you need a FILE_APPEND flag.
 } else { // If there's no POST data, the values are retrieved from the storage
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('information.txt')); // Retrieve the contents of the text file and decode them back into an array
    $senator = $data[0];
 $cmicrophone = $data[1];
    $microphone = $data[2];
 $words = $data[3];
 }
 echo "". $senator. "" .$cmicrophone. "" .$microphone. "";

 $wordformat = wordwrap($words, 32, "\n", false);
 
 echo "".$words. "";
 
 
 ?>
```

If the code is correct, would it just be the

> $.getJSON()

location isn't correct? The variables are all correct.

Comment: what is that `"#host/information.txt"` ?

Comment: @hassan path to my txt file in my winscp

Comment: it is not a valid path, what is the `#` doing here ?

Comment: it's just a variable. My question is that this doesnt work because my path isn't correct or the code is actually not right. @hassan